# Problem to access a page of the site ReactJS , React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to ReactJS and I have a problem in my project : a page of the site is not displayed. I'm showing you the parts of the code that deal with the question.
Here is the component of the first page where the redirect to the second page is located:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import * as years from "./years.json";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 150
  },
  floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
    //   color: "white"
  }
}));

const year = years.years;

export default function Select() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleRouter = value => {
    setValue(value);
    // console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
      {value !== null && <Redirect to={value} />}
      <Autocomplete
        id="standard-select-currency-native"
        className={classes.input}
        options={year}
        onChange={(event, value) => handleRouter(value)}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Choix de l'année"
            InputLabelProps={{
              className: classes.floatingLabelFocusStyle
            }}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Here is the component of the second page where the redirect to the third page is located:

```
    export default function YearChoice(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const handleRouter = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

 
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      className={classes.grid}
      spacing={0}
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justify="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      textAlign="center"
    >
      {value !== null && <Redirect to={value} />}
      <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined" justifyContent="center">
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom className={classes.title}>
            Statistiques de l'année 2020
          </Typography>
          <FormControl component="fieldset">
            {/* <RadioGroup onChange={handleRouter}> */}
            {Array.isArray(country) &&
              country.map(options => (
                <FormControlLabel
                  key={options}
                  value={options}
                  control={<Button onClick={handleRouter} />}
                  label={options}
                  className={classes.button}
                />
              ))}
            {/* </RadioGroup> */}
          </FormControl>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

then there's the routes file:

```
    import Dashboard from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import DashboardPage from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.js";
import YearChoice from "views/YearChoice/YearChoice.js";
import CountryStats from "views/CountryStats/CountryStats.js";

const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    icon: Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPage,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/:year",
    name: "YearChoice",
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    component: YearChoice,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
  {
    path: "/:country",
    name: "CountryStats",
    rtlName: "لوحة القيادة",
    component: CountryStats,
    layout: "/admin"
  }
];
```

here is the admin file:

```
    import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
// creates a beautiful scrollbar
import PerfectScrollbar from "perfect-scrollbar";
import "perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css";
// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// core components
import Navbar from "components/Navbars/Navbar.js";
// import Footer from "components/Footer/Footer.js";
// import FixedPlugin from "components/FixedPlugin/FixedPlugin.js";

import routes from "routes.js";

import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/layouts/adminStyle.js";

import bgImage from "assets/img/background.jpg";

let ps;

const switchRoutes = (
  <Switch>
    {routes.map((prop, key) => {
      if (prop.layout === "/admin") {
        return (
          <Route
            path={prop.layout + prop.path}
            component={prop.component}
            key={key}
          />
        );
      }
      return null;
    })}
    {/* <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard" /> */}
  </Switch>
);

[...]

    return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <div className={classes.mainPanel} ref={mainPanel}>
        <Navbar />
        {/* <div className={classes.backgroundImage}></div> */}
        {/* On the /maps route we want the map to be on full screen - this is not possible if the content and conatiner classes are present because they have some paddings which would make the map smaller */}
        {getRoute() ? (
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.container}>{switchRoutes}</div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={classes.map}>{switchRoutes}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and finally the index file:

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./redux/store/configureStore";
// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";

import "assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.8.0";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

So I can't understand why I can't get to the last page when I can easily make my way from the first to the second page.
I thank those who will take the time to consult my problem and those who will be able to help me.

Comment: with last page you mean `/:country` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, and I can't figure out why it's not working.